# Google Maps API Reactnative Find nearby cabs

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am creating an app like uber in Reactnative. In that app I wish to add a Google maps api to find the nearest cab driver. And also I want to show number of cabs available in that area (during zoom in and out) as shown in uber.

I am using firebase cloud firestore as a database.